# Python compare-sort only compares neighbors

Tags: python, sorting, compare

Following code sorts a list of objects.

What I want to achieve is to sort objects of type 'boring' by their value. I don't care about their position in the list, but at the end they need to be sorted. My code only compares neighbors, therefore in the end  and  are still in wrong order.

What type of sort algorithm needs to be applied to have them sorted correctly?

```
class SortMe:
    def __init__(self, type, value):
        self.type = type
        self.value = value
    def __repr__(self):
        return "<%s %s %s>" % (self.__class__.__name__, self.type, self.value)

stack = (
    SortMe('fancy', 15),
    SortMe('fancy', 3),
    SortMe('boring', 3),
    SortMe('boring', 1),
    SortMe('fancy', 1),
    SortMe('boring', 22),
    SortMe('fancy', 22),
    SortMe('fancy', 17),
    SortMe('boring', 5),
    )

def compare(a1, a2):
    if a1.type == 'boring' and a2.type == 'boring':
        if a1.value > a2.value:
            return 1
        elif a1.value < a2.value:
            return -1
        else:
            return 0
    else:
        return 0

stack = sorted(stack, cmp=compare)

print '\n'.join(map(str, stack))
```

Current output (boring objects in wrong order):

```
<SortMe fancy 15>
<SortMe fancy 3>
<SortMe boring 1>
<SortMe boring 3>
<SortMe fancy 1>
<SortMe boring 22>
<SortMe fancy 22>
<SortMe fancy 17>
<SortMe boring 5>
```

Intended output (boring in right order, position doesn't matter):

```
<SortMe fancy 15>
<SortMe fancy 3>
<SortMe boring 1>
<SortMe boring 3>
<SortMe fancy 1>
<SortMe boring 5>
<SortMe boring 22>
<SortMe fancy 22>
<SortMe fancy 17>
```

or:

```
<SortMe fancy 15>
<SortMe fancy 3>
<SortMe fancy 1>
<SortMe fancy 22>
<SortMe fancy 17>
<SortMe boring 1>
<SortMe boring 3>
<SortMe boring 5>
<SortMe boring 22>
```

or so.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use a `cmp` key, just extract the value directly using `key` function instead:

```
sorted(stack, key=lambda v: v.value if v.type == 'boring' else None)
```

which produces:

```
>>> for sm in sorted(stack, key=lambda v: v.value if v.type == 'boring' else None):
...     print sm
... 
<SortMe fancy 15>
<SortMe fancy 3>
<SortMe fancy 1>
<SortMe fancy 22>
<SortMe fancy 17>
<SortMe boring 1>
<SortMe boring 3>
<SortMe boring 5>
<SortMe boring 22>
```

Your `cmp` key approach still returns `0` when comparing any `fancy` `SortMe` object with a `boring` one, in whatever order they were in, creating an inconsistent sorting. You'd need to consistently return `-1` or `1` when comparing two objects that differ in type instead:

```
def compare(a1, a2):
    if a1.type == 'boring' and a2.type == 'boring':
        return cmp(a1.value, a2.value)
    else:
        # sort fancy before boring, reverse order
        return cmp(a2.type, a1.type)
```

where I reused the `cmp()` built-in function to return the appropriate `-1`, `0` or `1` values:

```
>>> def compare(a1, a2):
...     if a1.type == 'boring' and a2.type == 'boring':
...         return cmp(a1.value, a2.value)
...     else:
...         return cmp(a2.type, a1.type)
... 
>>> for sm in sorted(stack, compare):
...     print sm
... 
<SortMe fancy 15>
<SortMe fancy 3>
<SortMe fancy 1>
<SortMe fancy 22>
<SortMe fancy 17>
<SortMe boring 1>
<SortMe boring 3>
<SortMe boring 5>
<SortMe boring 22>
```

Comment: Yay. StackOverflow FTW! Thank you.